# Starting a Kubeflow managment cluster on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, kubeflow, kpt

So currently I am trying to set up this Management Cluster through the Google Cloud shell using [this](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/deploy/management-setup/) guide. However, I have been facing along the steps.

First one is the fact that that kpt does not seem to have any `kpt cfg` functionality anymore. To combat this, I have downloaded the binary for `kpt 0.39.3`. because the latest one gives me the error:

```
error: unknown command "cfg" for "kpt"

Did you mean this?
        fn
        pkg
```

So I made the `Kptfile` locally using `0.39.3` and then placed it in the directory for Google Cloud Shell to pickup. Now when I call `make apply-cluster`, I get the error:

```
I0824 03:23:40.084196    1255 main.go:230] reconcile serviceusage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/Service container.googleapis.com
Unexpected error: error reconciling objects: error reconciling Service:PROJECT/container.googleapis.com: error fetching service "projects/PROJECT/services/container.googleapis.com": googleapi: Error 400: The resource id projects/PROJECT is invalid.
```

But I know for a fact that this is a functional

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried to follow the guide you mentioned [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/deploy/management-setup/) and everything worked for me.

In order to avoid your fist error I decided to erase the kpt using `gcloud components remove kpt`, and install the old one which is fully compatible with this kubeflow guide using this [link](https://googlecontainertools.github.io/kpt/installation/binaries/).

Regarding your second error when you call the `make apply-cluster` and you receive the `The resource id projects/PROJECT is invalid` it can be related to not set the values [accordingly](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/deploy/management-setup/#configure-kpt-setter-values)